# WPF contextmenu is slow with many items - how can I speed it up?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have found the context menu takes over 10 seconds to display when I have 10,000 items in it, I'd like to make this faster (e.g. less than 1 second)

Here is my test code that shows the context menu slowness directly:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
                mi.Header = "test";                 // this is HOT - 3%
                mi.Tag = this;                      // cold
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    MenuItem mi2 = new MenuItem();  // this is HOT - 1%
                    mi2.Header = "test";            // this is HOT - 12%
                    mi2.Tag = this;                 // cold
                    mi.Items.Add(mi2);              // this is HOT - 6%
                }
                cm.Items.Add(mi);                   // this is HOT - 3%
            }
            cm.IsOpen = true;                       // this is HOT - 72%
        }
```

According to performance profilers I've used, the cm.IsOpen is taking most of the time - but setting the mi.Header is also significant.

Comment: Why are you making an unusable context menu?

Comment: Exactly my thoughts ... menus work well with roughly up to 9 items. Stuffing 10k items in there is not only nonsense, it's insane.

Comment: Woah, 10000 items in a context menu, I would dislike said context menu.

Comment: @Joey @Gabe I agree that having 1k items at a single level is unusable, but having 10k items overall is perhaps not. If the context menu represented some sort of taxonomy\categorization, then it would be feasible to have less items at each level, but to simply have more levels. The context menu would then act more like a tree. We use trees that represent potentially millions of items every day e.g. explorer.

Comment: @chibacity: Nothing wrong with large trees, but not as a menu. [Nested fly-out menus are a usability nightmare](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/23/4517137.aspx).

Comment: @Joey That's a very interesting point, it's not a truism though. Sub-menus are not always a 'nightmare', but should be carefully considered in any balanced UX design.

Comment: @Joey I'm pretty sure that what Raymond is describing is not the standard behaviour of context menus i.e. the 'collapsing menu problem' he describes. But anyway, I'm not advocated horribly complex context menus, so you'll no argument form me there. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's going to be a poor user experience having 1k items at a single level, but how to make context menus with lots\expensive items more responsive, is a fair question.

The general pattern I use is to initially create my menu with dummy sub-menus. The dummy sub-menus have a single place-holder menu item and I hook the sub-menu opening event. In the event handler I remove the place-holder menu item and add the real items in.

This pattern allows sub-menus to be created on demand and only if the sub-menu is actually opened. In other words it makes your menu dynamic meaning you do not have to create everything up-front, nor create hundreds of sub-menus which will not be opened.

This pattern would reduce your initial menu item count from 10k items to 1k for the example above. This should get you down to ~1 second.

Again 10k menu items with 1k in the root is pretty much unusable in terms of UX. I hope this is just a thought experiment! :)

**Example**

```
        ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
            mi.Header = "test";
            mi.Tag = this;

            object dummySub = new object();
            mi.Items.Add(dummySub);
            cm.Items.Add(mi);

            mi.SubmenuOpened += delegate
            {
                mi.Items.Clear();

                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    MenuItem mi2 = new MenuItem();
                    mi2.Header = "test";
                    mi2.Tag = this;
                    mi.Items.Add(mi2);
                }
            };
        }

        cm.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: Yes this does make it much faster.  The reason for so many items is outside of my control - and I agree with @Joey that it is good to avoid too many levels.  Hopefully once I make it faster the users will start complaining instead about the practicality of it and opt for change.

Comment: @Lance Sounds like an interesting situation. Happy to be of help. :)

Comment: @chibacity: thanks for a nice clear working example of dynamic submenu generation!

Comment: I think the pattern is known as "lazy loading" and used in many places. But I must confess I wouldn't have expected to see it used in menus.